# Animating Div Width and Position with Jquery (or The Case of the Disappearing Div)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, position

SO,

I've put together a JSfiddle of two adjacent DIVs inside a container div. The two child divs are supposed to expand horizontally to fill the container when the cursor hovers over them. This works fine with the leftmost DIV, but when I try the same animation with the child DIV to the right (that is, the DIV which must expand in *both* directions to fill the container), it doesn't run smoothly. I've tried to animate the child DIV's movement to the left edge of the container and its expansion simultaneously, but the properties don't work in the script I'm using. Any thoughts, SO?

See the JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/F84FA/32/). (**This fiddle is obsolete, for the updated version see below**)

**EDIT:**

I've made progress on animating the DIV's movement to the left using this JScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#profdevcontainer").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: '1005px',
            marginLeft: '-170px',
            // 'z-index': '99'
        }, 'fast');
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: '250px',
            marginLeft: '0px'
        }, 'fast');   
    });
});
```

But when the DIV's animation is nearly complete, it disappears as you can see in the updated [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/bVPwT/30/). I'm sure this has something to do with the overflow property of my parent container, but the only possible reasons I can think of are:

1. There's a conflict between the CSS properties I'm applying on hover and the properties I'm animating with javascript,
2. The animated dimensions are somehow triggering the overflow.

These is the CSS for the div in question:

```
#profdevcontainer {
width: 250px;
height: 60px;
background-color: yellow;
float: left;
margin-right: 3px;
}

#profdevcontainer:hover {
/* animated wit css / width: 1005px; */
/* animated wit css / height: 60px;
/* animated wit css / background-color: yellow;
/* animated wit css / float: left; */
/* position: absolute; */
z-index: 99;
margin-right: 3px; 
}
```

Comment: Just as an FYI - comments in CSS are `/* */`, not `//`. Also, as an answer to your question - you're attempting to animate a value of `left:auto` to `left:0` - this is causing your jump. Look into `.position()` or `.offset()` for your answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the desired effect by animating a negative left margin for the DIVs to guide them to just the right spot and avoid flicker. The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/WTcZc/22/embedded/result/).